# How to post multiple images using HttpWebRequest in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my application I want to post multiple images using HttpWebRequest. Write now I am able to do so with one image. Is there any possibility to send multiple images using HttpWebRequest in windows phone 7 application? If so, please I need to know how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to combine the images in a custom data format (a unique separator should be fine - like multi-part MIME formatting) and then have the server split the data up and turn it back into separate files at the other end.

There's an eample of uploading in this way at http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/796584-how-upload-multiple-files-using-httpwebrequest-c

As an alternative you could just zip all the files together and send the zip as a single file.

Comment: Hi Matt Lacey, thanks this links help me a lot for posting multiple image files. Sorry for replying so late but thank you so much. This is what i wann. Regards, Panache.